# Thank you Stefano Palazzo!

Tags: discussion, community, moderators

I would like to thank [Stefano Palazzo](https://askubuntu.com/users/1067/stefano-palazzo) for their contribution to the Ask Ubuntu community and also for moderating Ask Ubuntu for 9 years.

Stefano was one of the [longest-serving moderators](https://askubuntu.com/election/1) in Ask Ubuntu and it's sad to see that [Stefano is no longer a moderator](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19332).

In case if you're reading this Stefano..... I hope you'll continue helping the community though you're not a moderator. May the Force be with you!

---

I would love to hear from the Ask Ubuntu community about the nostalgic experiences which they had with Stefano (since I'm a pretty new member of the Ask Ubuntu community).

P.S. Here's the link to Stefano's moderator nomination post: https://askubuntu.com/election/1#post-24227

Comment: What's happening with the votes?....

Comment: To guess, the downvotes are because people usually write their own good bye posts. It is unusual to see one of these written by a third party and people may just think it is a bit inappropriate to post this if Stefano did not want to make a fuss about it. Also, we don't know what happened to Stefano, perhaps (though unlikely)  he was fired for some reason and people are pissed at him? Again these are just guesses, I don't know peoples reasoning for a fact.

Comment: My post is not exactly a good bye post. It was just a thank you post. @MarkKirby

Comment: Sure, I am just putting out reasons why this might get some down votes as I highly doubt the downvoters will come back to give their actual reasons. Personally, I don't have an issue with it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for giving your opinion! @MarkKirby

Comment: I strongly suggest to delete this post, please

Comment: @αғsнιη Can you please let me know the reason?